# Fridge running too cold

Tags: refrigerator

My fridge recently appears to be keeping a temp much colder then it was; I believe this began at or shortly after our home briefly lost power. It is set to 39 F, I'm not sure if this was what it was set at before, but we have food now getting much colder then this (i.e. ice forming).

Could the power outage have faulted something? What's a common failure that would be the cause of this?

It is a Whirpool Fridge from 2013. Model number is WSF26C2EXB01.

Comment: "seems to be" is a bit vague. Get a thermometer and measure temperatures at top & bottom of both refrigerator and freezer.

Comment: I understand that, once I get thermometer I will add edit my post with this info.

Answer (score 0):

39 degrees is an appropriate fridge temperature.

You should check the internal vents and such. If those are blocked, the fridge can end up with an incorrect temperature. You also might try setting the temperature a degree higher, then a degree lower, just in case the internal system got confused.

[Manual](https://www.searspartsdirect.com/manual/u2a47k93nm-001198/whirlpool-wsf26c2exb01-side-by-side-refrigerator) page 11 has troubleshooting info.